# How to find first set?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction

I am trying to list the First set of a given grammar with this function:

**Note:** 
    `char c` - the character to find the first set;
    `first_set` - store elements of the corresponding first set;
    `q1`, `q2` - the previous position;
    `rule`- store all the grammar rule line by line listed below;
    for the first time the parameters are `('S', 0, 0)`.

```
void findfirst(char c, int q1, int q2){
    if(!(isupper(c)) || c=='$'){
         first_set[n++] = c;
    }
    for(int j=0;j<rule_number;j++){
        if(rule[j][0]==c){
            if(rule[j][2]==';'){
                if(rule[q1][q2]=='\0')
                    first_set[n++] = ';';
                else if(rule[q1][q2]!='\0' &&(q1!=0||q2!=0))
                    findfirst(rule[q1][q2], q1, (q2+1));
                else
                    first_set[n++] = ';';
            }
            else if(!isupper(rule[j][2]) || rule[j][2]=='$')
                first_set[n++] = rule[j][2];
            else
                findfirst(rule[j][2],j,3);
        }
    }
}
```

But found that if the given grammar looks like this:

```
S AC$
C c
C ;
A aBCd
A BQ
B bB
B ;
Q q
Q ;
```

(which the left hand side or any capital letters in the right hand side are non-terminal, and any small case letters are terminal) 
the function couldn't correctly output the first set for `S`, since it will stop at finding the first set of `Q` and store `';'` to the first set and won't go on to find `C`'s first set.

Does anyone have a clue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Get in the habit of documenting your code and using descriptive variable names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is extremely inefficient to compute FIRST sets one at a time, since they are interdependent. For example, in order to compute the FIRST set of `A` , you need to also compute the FIRST set of `B`, and then because `B` can derive the emoty string, you need the FIRST set of `Q`.

Most algorithms compute all of them in parallel, using some variation of a transitive closure algorithm. You can do this with a depth-first search, which seems to be what you are attempting, but it might be easier to implement the least fixed point algorithm described in the Dragon book (and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LL_parser#Constructing_an_LL(1)_parsing_table).

Either way, you will probably find it easier to first compute NULLABLE (that is, which non-terminals derive the empty set). There is a simple linear-time algorithm for that (linear in the size of the grammar), which again is easy to find.

If you are doing this work as part of a class, you'll probably find the relevant algorithms in your course materials. Alternatively, you can look for a copy of the [Dragon book](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools) or other similar text books.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't even think of efficiency :(

Answer (score 0):

You could do like the following `code`:

`used[i]` means the `rule[i]` is used or not

The method is `Depth-first search`, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search

```
#include <iostream>

#define MAX_SIZE 1024

char rule[][10] = {
  "S AC$",
  "C c",
  "C ;",
  "A aBCd",
  "A BQ",
  "B bB",
  "B ;",
  "Q q",
  "Q ;"
};

constexpr int rule_number = sizeof(rule) / sizeof(rule[0]);

char first_set[MAX_SIZE];

bool findfirst(int row, int col, int *n, bool* used) {
  for (;;) {
    char ch = rule[row][col];
    if (ch == '$' || ch == ';' || ch == '\0') {
      first_set[*n] = '\0';
      break;
    }
    if (islower(ch)) {
      first_set[(*n)++] = ch;
      ++col;
      continue;
    }
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i != rule_number; ++i) {
      if (used[i] == true || rule[i][0] != ch)
        continue;
      used[i] = true;
      int k = *n;
      if (findfirst(i, 2, n, used) == true)
        break;
      used[i] = false;
      *n = k;
    }
    if (i == rule_number)
      return false;
    ++col;
  }
  return true;
}

int main() {
  bool used[rule_number];
  int n = 0;
  for (int i = 2; rule[0][i] != '$' && rule[0][i] != '\0'; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j != rule_number; ++j)
      used[j] = false;
    used[0] = true;
    findfirst(0, i, &n, used);
  }
  std::cout << first_set << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```